# evaluation of a semi-supervised ranking model

Tags: testing, machine-learning, evaluation

I learned ranking model with graph-based semi-supervised approach, while labeled(just positive) and unlabeled(positive and negative) data is both used in training. With the model, all of the data could be ranked with a score after the training processing. Is there any way to evaluate the system just by the positive labeled data if I do not want to label the unlabeled data?
 Actually I would like to randomly split the positive labeled into two parts, and keep half as positive and half as unlabeled for the further evaluation. But I did not find a good metric.